# Need help to prove how equation 2 is obtained from equation 1

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, chain-rule

Im a undergradute student, and I have little expirience with vector calculus.

Can someone help me to obation equation 2 from equation 1:
where $\vec{k}$ is the wavenumber vector and $\vec{r}$ the position vector. The conxtext is electromanetism.

Equation 1:
$\nabla \times\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon(\vec{r})} \nabla \times\left(e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \vec{u}_{\vec{k}}(\vec{r})\right)\right)=\left(\frac{\omega(\vec{k})}{c}\right)^{2} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \vec{u}_{\vec{k}}(\vec{r})$

**This is a tip a got:** Applying the chain rule to take the curl of the exponential term explicitly, we can move it outside
of the operators and cancel from both sides:

Equation 2:\begin{aligned}
(i \vec{k}+\nabla) \times \frac{1}{\epsilon(\vec{r})}(i \vec{k}+\nabla) \times \vec{u}_{\vec{k}}(\vec{r}) &=\left(\frac{\omega(\vec{k})}{c}\right)^{2} \vec{u}_{\vec{k}} 
\end{aligned}

I am aplying this entity twice:
$\nabla \times(\psi \mathbf{A})=\psi(\nabla \times \mathbf{A})+\nabla \psi \times \mathbf{A}$

but at the end I have two terms that I think somehow by a physics instuition or explaniantion I can justify they are zero.

Here is my try:

I start applying the identity:
$\nabla \times(\psi \mathbf{A})=\psi(\nabla \times \mathbf{A})+\nabla \psi \times \mathbf{A}$

And get:
$\nabla \times \frac{1}{\varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})}\left[e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}\left(\nabla \times \mathrm{u}_{\mathrm{k}}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})\right)+\nabla e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \times \mathrm{u}_{\mathrm{k}}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})\right]=\left(\frac{\omega(\vec{k})}{c}\right)^{2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \overrightarrow{\mathrm{k}} \cdot \overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}}} \mathrm{u}_{\mathrm{k}}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})$

Now I tried to compute:$\nabla e^{\vec{i} \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\nabla e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}=\frac{\partial e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}}{\partial x} \hat{\imath}+\frac{\partial e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}}{\partial y} \hat{\jmath}+\frac{\partial e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}}{\partial z} \hat{k} \\
=\left(\frac{\partial i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}{\partial x} \hat{\imath}+\frac{\partial i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}{\partial y} \hat{\jmath}+\frac{\partial i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}{\partial z} \hat{k}\right) e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \\
=\left\{\left(i \frac{\partial \vec{k}}{\partial x} \cdot \vec{r}+i \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial x} \cdot \vec{k}\right) i+\left(i \frac{\partial \vec{k}}{\partial y} \cdot \vec{r}+i \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial y} \cdot \vec{k}\right) \hat{\jmath}+\left(i \frac{\partial \vec{k}}{\partial z} \cdot \vec{r}+i \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial z} \cdot \vec{k}\right) \hat{k}\right\}=i \vec{k}
\end{array}
$$
I am not sure if the previous result is correct. But assuming is right:
$\nabla \times \frac{1}{\varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}\left[\left(\nabla \times u_{k}(\vec{r})\right)+i \vec{k} \times u_{k}(\vec{r})\right]=\left(\frac{\omega(\vec{k})}{c}\right)^{2} \mathrm{e}^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} u_{k}(\vec{r})$

now, I rename the term:

$$
\left[\left(\nabla \times u_{k}(\vec{r})\right)+i \vec{k} \times u_{k}(\vec{r})\right]=[\nabla+i \vec{k}] \times u_{k}(\vec{r}) \equiv \vec{A}
$$
SO
$$
\nabla \times \frac{1}{\varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \vec{A}=\left(\frac{\omega(\vec{k})}{c}\right)^{2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \overrightarrow{\mathrm{k}} \cdot \overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}}} \mathrm{u}_{\mathrm{k}}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})
$$
applying the identity again:
$$
\nabla \times \gamma \overrightarrow{\mathrm{B}}=\gamma(\nabla \times \overrightarrow{\mathrm{B}})+(\nabla \gamma) \times \overrightarrow{\mathrm{B}}
$$
but I do not know if in this case $\gamma$ would be:
$\gamma=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_{r}(\vec{r})} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}$ or $\gamma=e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}},$ where $\varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})$ is the dielectric configuration

If I take $\gamma=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_{r}(\vec{r})} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} $ I get

$$
\nabla \times\left[\frac{1}{\varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}(\nabla \times \overrightarrow{\mathrm{A}})+\nabla \frac{1}{\varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \times \overrightarrow{\mathrm{A}}\right]=\left(\frac{\omega(\vec{k})}{c}\right)^{2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \overrightarrow{\mathrm{k}} \cdot \overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}}} \mathrm{u}_{\mathrm{k}}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})
$$
But
$$
\nabla \frac{1}{\varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}=\frac{\varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}}) \nabla e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}-e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \nabla \varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})}{\left(\varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})\right)^{2}}=\frac{i \vec{k}}{\varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}-\frac{e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \nabla \varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})}{\left(\varepsilon_{r}(\overrightarrow{\mathrm{r}})\right)^{2}}
$$

any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please, include all the necessary information in this post.

Comment: @Joel  what is it missing? I can see all the information needed on the post

Comment: He means, do not do it by screen shot.  That cannot be searched for.  It may disappear in the future.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you I have added the math with text